# List is not printing out one of the variables

Tags: java, list, arraylist

The code below stores the radius and value in its list. But when I go to print the values, it only prints the radius not the other variable value. I don't understand why its not printing it out.

Here is my code:

```
public class AddingBoth {

private double radius;
private double value;
private List<AddingBoth> list = new ArrayList<AddingBoth>();

public AddingBoth(double radius, double value){
    this.radius = radius;
    this.value = value;
    list.add(this);
}

public List<AddingBoth> getList(){
    return list;
}

public double getRadius(){
    return radius;
}

public double getValue(){
    return value;
}

public void print(){
    Iterator<AddingBoth> iter = list.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iter.next().getRadius()+"    ");
    }

    System.out.println("This is the value;  ");
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        System.out.println("Value:    "+iter.next().getValue());
    }
}
 }
```

And this is where I am calling my class:

```
   AddingBoth ab = null;

         for(int i =0; i< 256; i++){
             int y=0;
                while(y<256){
                    //image.getPixel(i, y);
                    String x = image.getLocationAsString(i, y);
                    String n = image.getValueAsString(i, y);
                    //System.out.println(x);

                    String delim = ", value=";
                    String [] tokens = n.split(delim);
                    double num = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);

                    //if(image.getR() < 1.43){
                        String [] t = x.split("r=");
                        String[] b = t[1].split(" mm/c");
                        //System.out.print("Meet b:    "+b[0]);
                        double radius = Double.parseDouble(b[0]);

                        String [] theta = x.split("theta= ");
                        String [] token2 = theta[1].split(Character.toString(IJ.degreeSymbol));
                        float thetaNum = Float.parseFloat(token2[0]);
                        //System.out.print("  This is the theta value:    "+thetaNum+"    ");

                    ab = new AddingBoth(radius, num);
                    ab.print();
                        y++;
                }
         }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll need to get rid of the second `iter.hasNext() block.  You want both print statements inside the same loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your print method should be simplified, and you probably really want something like this -

```
public void print(){
  for (AddingBoth ab : list) {
    // Is your radius really a String?
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(ab.getRadius()) + " = " + ab.getValue());
  }
  // As the other answers point out you had already exhausted the iterator.
  System.out.flush();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I don't know if I am on the right track or not but I am suppose to get all the radius and amplitudes and then I am suppose to look for any duplicates in radius and if they are I am suppose to add the values (amplitude) of the radius and delete the duplicates. I thought list would be a good idea but I don't know if it will work. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this, or is this the best way?

Comment: @selena Great. That's a new question (so ask one). But, I wouldn't ask it here, I'd ask on the [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: isn't that site for math questions only?

Comment: "I am suppose to get all the radius and amplitudes and then I am suppose to look for any duplicates in radius and if they are I am suppose to add the values (amplitude) of the radius" sounds like math to me. At the risk of demonstrating my own ignorance on the subject, **what** is the *amplitude* of a radius? Are they measured in something besides degrees and radians now?

Comment: But I need to code this instead. I have used linked lists, array lists, if-else and for loops and some are successful but not very efficient. I'm just looking for a efficient programming way.

Comment: Wait, a [Vector2d](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/javase/technologies/desktop/java3d/forDevelopers/J3D_1_3_API/j3dapi/javax/vecmath/Vector2d.html)? So a direction and a velocity in that direction?

Answer (score 3):

Since you've run over the iterator until it has no more values, you've exhausted it, and you'll never enter the second `while` loop.

One way to avoid this is to use a fresh iterator for the second loop:

```
public void print(){
    Iterator<AddingBoth> iter = list.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(iter.next().getRadius()+"    ");
    }

    System.out.println("This is the value;  ");
    iter = list.iterator(); // new iterator!
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        System.out.println("Value:    "+iter.next().getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `Iterator` twice, which is causing your issue.  Basically, you go all the way through the list and then while you're at the end, you ask if there's another element in the list (which there isn't).  The list doesn't restart when you reach the end.

Instead of two while loops, just use one.

```
public void print(){
    Iterator<AddingBoth> iter = list.iterator();
    AddingBoth temp;
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        temp = iter.next();
        System.out.println(temp.getRadius()+"    ");
        System.out.println("Value:    "+temp.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: This will fail, because you call `iter.next()` twice. You need a temporary variable.